# "Invalid date" error when converting a string to date

Tags: javascript

Am trying to convert a string to date

```
var strdate='2014-04-23+09:06:57.4830591330'
```

while trying to convert this string to date using below code

```
var followupDate =  new Date(strdate);

console.log(followupDate)
```

am getting the error

```
Date {Invalid Date}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a space rather than an addition sign, so you could just replace it:

```
var strdate='2014-04-23+09:06:57.4830591330';
var followupDate =  new Date(strdate.replace("+"," "));
console.log(followupDate);
```

Will log something like: `Wed Apr 23 2014 09:06:57 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the <kbd>+</kbd> sign in your string for a space, between the year and the hours.

To explain this, let's see [Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) :

> #### dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a
> format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
> timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Now, [from RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) (under *3.3. Date and Time Specification*), it's explicitly described that the <kbd>+</kbd> is meant for timezones:

> zone  = (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone

**Moreover, note that there's no room for milliseconds in this standard.**

Answer (score 0):

Your String Format is Wrong
It should be like this

```
var strdate = "2014-04-23 09:06:57.4830591330"
```

if you are getting your value dynamicaly then change it to this format by

```
var newstrdate = strdate.replace("+", " ");
```

and then try

```
date = new Date(newstrdate);
```